# Open source alternatives to telerik grid for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datagrid, user-controls, open-source

I work for an IT shop that doesn't have budget to pay for controls. Is there an open source alternative to telerik grid for mvc? I would like a rich datagrids for my pages.

Comment: you can take look this link for 12 opensource mvc grid controls http://www.dotnetspan.com/2014/12/opensource-gridview-control-for-aspnet-mvc5.html

Comment: I can recommend https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables :D

Comment: http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's also the [`MVCContrib.Grid`](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) that you might take a look at.

And if you are looking for a pure client side grid, there are gazillions of them like [`jqGrid`](http://www.trirand.com/blog/), [`FuelUX datagrid`](http://exacttarget.github.com/fuelux/#datagrid), ...

Comment: This is still the first google result for "mvc open source datagrid" so I'd suggest an edit: grid is not in the part of the kendo ui framework that telerik open-sourced.

Answer (score 7):

**Grid.MVC** is an open source and working Grid with **sorting and paging**

(and unlike telerik you do not need to change anything on controller side just add reference in your view and use.)

To install nugget package ([Install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc/))

```
PM> Install-Package Grid.Mvc -Version 3.0.0
```

In your view you can auto-create columns as below **(or customize see [User Guide](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Home))**

```
@using GridMvc.Html

@Html.Grid(Model).AutoGenerateColumns()
```

**See [Online Demo](http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/)**

Comment: It is a dead project

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Mvc Contrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid). I've had good experience using this.

Another option is [Webgrid](http://www.webgrid.com/). Source is availabe in [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webgrid/)